# Spring Java - How to change values of property in applicationContext.xml while web.xml running

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, applicationcontext

I'm working on web.xml, and it calls applicationContext.xml so forth..

While application is running, the value of property is changed by Database.

I use cronTriggerSchedule which is embedded into applicationContext.xml .Eventhough value`${sched1}` is changed, cronTriggerSchedule is not aware of this change.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean name="dailyCountJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.honorius.job.CurrencyAddJob"/>
    <property name="group" value="DailyJobs"/>
    <property name="durability" value="true"/>
    <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dailyCountJobCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="dailyCountJob"/>
    <property name="group" value="DailyJobsTriggers"/>
    <!--<property name="cronExpression" ref="cronExpression"/>-->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${sched1}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="schedProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:ex.properties" />  
</bean>
```

ex.properties:

```
sched1=0/1 * * * * ?
```

CurrencyAddJob.java:

```
 FileInputStream in2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HonoriusPc\\Desktop\\workspace\\honorius\\src\\main\\resources\\ex.properties");
        Properties props2 = new Properties();
        props2.load(in2);
        in2.close();
        FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\HonoriusPc\\Desktop\\workspace\\honorius\\src\\main\\resources\\ex.properties");
        props2.setProperty("sched1", sched); //BOUNDED WITH DATABASE.
        props2.store(out2,null);
        out2.close();
```

After application is stopped and rerun, then the new value set to cronTriggerSchedule. But i want these changes to apply  to application concurrently.

How do i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Spring bean XMLs are just parsed once. But you can update a bean value by calling the beans setter

```
jobTrigger.setCronExpression(...);
```